# Did the crime rate in Norway drop 31% after Muslims were deported?

Tags: criminology, muslims, norway

A [racist meme was posted on Quora](https://mememilitiaexposingcorruptglobalism.quora.com/ti-130999586) in November 2023 claims that Norway deported Muslims and the crime rate dropped by 31%.

**Warning**: Image below contains an offensive cartoon.

> [image]

Did Norway deport Muslims? Was that correlated with a drop in crime by 31%?

Comment: Somewhat vague when that's supposed to have happened. Apparently in 2020 https://www.facebook.com/400225720839953/posts/courtesy-norway-medianorway-waking-upnorway-deports-muslims-crime-rate-drops-31-/677432626452593/

Comment: Are we just supposed to ignore the racist meme?

Comment: @JeromeViveiros I'm not sure we *can* ignore it, as it appears to be the source of the claim.

Comment: Deleted comments that said this was easy to answer, and then failed to use the answer box to do so

Comment: @Fizz: Based on that 2020 link, I get the impression it is a copy of something written around 2014.

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes for a good question. The claim is extremely vague, since there's no year or timeframe, or explanation what "deports muslims" means. If there is a drop of the crime rate from any one year to another (say cherry-picking 1977 and 2002), would that answer this question "yes" (assuming there were any deportations in that timefame, which seems likely)?

Comment: This is a more-original 2016 version of the OP claim with the same offensive cartoon: https://www.sammyboy.com/threads/racist-norway-deports-good-muslims-anyhow-claim-crime-rate-down-by-30-since.223960/

Comment: @Oddthinking: The image in the post is really offensive, it is better to hide the image behind the url.

Comment: @C.F.G: Now behind a spoiler tag. Thanks.

Comment: When did Norway deport Muslims?

Answer (score 17):

I'm looking at the more [specific claim](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56410/did-the-crime-rate-in-norway-drop-31-after-muslims-were-deported) - with the same image and the 31% which DavePhD found:

> violent crimes are down more than 31% in less than a year

The post is from January 2016 and talks about deportations in 2014. And it references a post from May 2015, which in turn references [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418113750/http://toprightnews.com/heres-what-happened-when-one-nation-started-deporting-radical-muslims/) (now deleted) post from April 2015. It doesn't give a source for the 31% claim.

The [overall crime rate in Norway](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1179966/number-of-reported-crimes-in-norway/) is on a steady decline, but there has not been a significant drop in the relevant years:

[image: crime rate]

Looking at the number of [victims as it relates to deadly violence](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Comparison-of-deadly-violence-between-Sweden-Norway-Finland-and-Denmark-A-comparison_fig4_331869471), we can see a decline from 2013 to 2014 of around 30% (from about 42 victims to around 25). [Here's](https://www.macrotrends.net/countries/NOR/norway/murder-homicide-rate) also a graph of the homicide rate, including an annual percentage change, which also shows a decline of around 37% (the second source likely includes the 77 victims of the far-right terror attack in 2011, hence the big spike):

[image: victims per 100k]

We can also see that 2013 was an outlier, and that the total number of murder victims is relatively low. Using it as a measure of violent crime in general is not useful. But this is the closest I could come to finding a 30% reduction in anything relating to crime. Looking at the larger context makes it clear that the reduction cannot be explained by any deportations in 2014.

Looking at the [total number reported violent crimes](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1180013/number-of-reported-violent-crimes-in-norway/) (the source is the police of Norway), we can see a decline from 2013 to 2014 of 2.5%, which is much lower than the 31% from the claim:

[image: violent crime rate]

Comment: What about the other half of the claim? How many Muslims were deported, if any?

Comment: @Laurel I didn't look at that, because I think looking at crime stats is enough to disprove the claim. I also doubt that there are official statistics regarding the religion of those that are deported (at least I couldn't find any).

Comment: Article talking about the *claim* that Norway deported Muslims. Spoiler alert: they didn't. https://www.truthorfiction.com/norway-targets-muslims-for-deportation-crime-rate-drops/